# Manuscripts and Minuscules

Tags: history, manuscript

I came across the concept of minuscules quite recently. Wikipedia says that they are manuscripts written with small font sizes. How do they matter more or less than any other Christian manuscript? Is there any particular relevance to minuscules apart from being used heavily for the translation of the Bible?

Comment: See >>  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categories_of_New_Testament_manuscripts

Comment: They're not written in small font sizes, they're written with lower-case letters. The earlier manuscripts were written in ALLCAPS (because lower-case letters hadn't been invented yet.)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Testament_minuscule

Comment: read the books like "THE TEXT OF THE NEW TESTAMENT, its text transmission and corruption" by Ehrman and Metzger. It is a valuable book describing in details the history of manuscripts and the evolution of the script and book making and everything

Comment: @Aron John Sabu Hi Aron, welcome to BH-Stack Exchange, we are glad you are here. Please be sure to take the [site tour](https://www.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) and read our [code of conduct](https://www.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/conduct). Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the New Testament books were written the handwriting was **uncials**, which looked more like capital letters, with no punctuation.

Uncials

[image]

Uncials

[image]

**Minuscules** introduced separate capital and small letters, word spacing, and punctuation (the basis of modern handwriting).  It didn't appear until the ninth century.

> Minuscule

> A modified form of Greek cursive handwriting (“rather small”), introduced in the 9th century c.e. More formal and more legible than ordinary cursive, minuscule writing enabled scribes to write more quickly and by the end of the 10th century supplanted uncial writing for literary purposes. Minuscules represent nearly 90 percent of extant NT manuscripts. (Logos Bible Software)

Minuscule

[image]

Comment: Excellent. Very informative. (Up-voted +1.)

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that manuscripts written in minuscule letters are of later dates than those written in capital or uncial letters. If I remember correctly, the oldest minuscule codeces date as early as the mid 9th century A.D.